# Pattern or best practice for a simple socket client app

Tags: android, sockets, client, chat

(This question has also been asked [in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37206/como-projetar-um-aplicativo-cliente-socket-b%C3%A1sico).)

First of all, apologies for the long text and for asking so many points in a single question. I thought it would be best to do that because they are interrelated and also because I think that anyone with experience in such kind of application (an Android socket client which keeps a persistent connection to a server for sending/receiving messages) would be able to answer all or many of those points. Basically I'm asking advice regarding a few design decisions about which I'm not sure what the 'recommended Android way of doing' is.

I'm trying to establish what is the best way to implement such an application (a socket client) in Android. It would use a socket communication technology such as WebSocket, Socket.IO, TCP, etc. to keep a persistent connection to a remote server for exchanging information. I don't have a specific case use to mention, except that it would probably not be a chat application, since the preffered technology for that is push notification (GCM or something similar). I'm thinking about an application which keeps the connection open as long as the user is 'logged in' it.

The connection should not be tied to the application's activities, i.e. messages can still be received after the user has left the app (eventually creating a Notification).

Questions I'm trying to answer in order to define such an application:

1. Should the connection handling (connect/disconnect) and message sending be delegated to a separate class (e.g. a Singleton)?
2. Choosing broadcasts to pass received messages to the current `Activity` seems to be okay; is there a more appropriate solution? Would an Event Bus or binding to a `Service` be preferable, even if the app architecture is fairly simple?
3. Considering that the connection must persist across process kills (as the system usually does to free up memory), would the best approach be to delegating the 'connect' action to a `Service` with an overridden `startCommand()` method returning `START_STICKY` (which allows the `Service` to restart as soon as the system's memory is available)? Is that the most appropriate approach? I guess so, since setting up periodic connection checks in `AlarmManager` sounds unnecessary in this case and using `startForeground()` doesn't prevent the application from being killed (it just makes that less likely to occur) and also shows an undesired notification to the user that the app is running.
4. As we come to agree on a design, I suppose wake locks will need to be added to it in order to prevent the device from staying/becoming asleep while the incoming/outgoing data is processed. I'm not sure how to add them to the final design though and I'm requesting clarification on that. I have in mind the following additional considerations:

   a) Incoming data is expected to wake up the device but not guaranteed to be fully processed before it goes back to sleep;

   b) The fact that the device is asleep as a connection to the server becomes available (which is signaled by a CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast) should not prevent a number of outgoing messages queued up in the app to be sent, however I don't know how to add a Wake Lock to this design in order to guarantee that the queue is fully processed;

   c) My protocol library may be prepared to work with Android (i.e. handles the I/O in one or more non-UI threads) but its callbacks may not be guaranteed to run in a non-UI thread (the library may delegate them to the UI thread). This may affect how I dispose Wake Locks through the code.
5. Do I need to keep an actively running thread loop in order to keep the connection open? How can I circumvent that?

Any feedback on those questions is appreciated.